# New Horizons at Pluto

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, image-processing

I recently posted this question on the signal processing site
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23768/new-horizons-at-pluto

The only answer was less detailed than I hoped for, so I'm trying here as well.

I'm teaching an undergraduate linear algebra course, and looking for applications.  The New Horizons spacecraft is approaching Pluto, and returning images I find fascinating:
http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/index.php

They briefly refer to 'image deconvolution'.  I expect they are using the most sophisticated tools available, some nonlinear, but my vague understanding is that some simple methods are linear algebra based.

Can anyone provide a reference or expository paper on linear algebra methods for image deconvolution that would be a good starting point?

Comment: [P.C. Hansen, Deconvolution and Regularization with Toeplitz Matrices](http://www.sintef-norge.com/globalassets/project/evitameeting/2005/deconv.pdf)

Comment: http://codingthematrix.com/ is good for linear algebra applications in computer science, including image manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[P.C. Hansen, Deconvolution and Regularization with Toeplitz Matrices](http://www.sintef.no/globalassets/project/evitameeting/2005/deconv.pdf).